# jQuery - pulling part of a url through regex

Tags: jquery, regex, string, search

I am trying to set a variable.  The variable should be parts of a Search query in the URL.  I'm assuming to use REGEX to achieve this.
IE URL: [http://tsqja.deznp.servertrust.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=**true**+ **glass**&x=0&y=0](http://tsqja.deznp.servertrust.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=true%20glass&x=0&y=0)

I want to pull the words 'true' and 'glass' in the example above and throw them in a jQuery variable.

ie. `var newKeys = $(search keys = some code);`

I am no good at using REGEX but would this just be my variable?

```
/^http:\/\/(tsqja\.)?deznp\.servertrust\./i,/Search=([^&]+)/i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this for a url alone or for the current url of the page the javascript is on? if the latter, it's as simple as

```
location.search.split("&")[0].split("=")[1]
```

otherwise you could do

```
var url = "http://tsqja.deznp.servertrust.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=true+glass&x=0&y=0";
url.match(/[?]Search=([^&]*)/)[1];
```

#### EDIT

So something like this might work (per your comments)

```
var url = "http://tsqja.deznp.servertrust.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=true+glass&x=0&y=0";
var theKeys = url.split("Search=")[1].split("&")[0].replace("+"," ");
```

Comment: The site wide URL is (in this example) tsqja.deznp.servertrust and the code will be placed in a template so on every page.  The URL I want is JUST for the url with the query `Search=` in it.

Comment: @ToddN but you only need true+glass when you're on a page with a url like `http://tsqja.deznp.servertrust.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=true+glass&x=0&y=0` correct?

Comment: In the first example, could I use `.split("Search=")` so it would only pull from the URL with `Search=` in it?

Comment: I actually need something like this to be the end all result:
`keys: theKeys //true glass`

Comment: @ToddN Yes you could, but you would probably need to do something like `url.split("Search=")[1].split("&")[0]` to just get the `true+glass`.

Comment: Ok so far I'm understanding.  It would pull `true+glass`, but I cannot have the `+` sign.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3733/discussion-between-toddn-and-joseph)